# android image rotating, imports error

Tags: android, image, rotation, import

Hi to all.

I'm having a problem with the imports. It's showing me errors on the imports and if I remove them the `JpegImageMetadata`, `Sanselan`, `ImageReadException`, `TiffImageMetadata`, `ExifTagConstants` can't be resolved to a type.

I'm using Android 2.3.3 and also tried Android 3.2, still had the same problem. Here are the imports:

```
import org.apache.sanselan.ImageReadException;
import org.apache.sanselan.Sanselan;
import org.apache.sanselan.formats.jpeg.JpegImageMetadata;
import org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.TiffImageMetadata;
import org.apache.sanselan.formats.tiff.constants.ExifTagConstants;
```

And this is the other part of the code that is showing the error (I can post the whole code if needed):

```
private int degreeRotated(String filePath) {
        try {
            JpegImageMetadata meta = ((JpegImageMetadata) Sanselan.getMetadata(new File(filePath)));
            TiffImageMetadata data = null;
            if (meta != null) {
                data = meta.getExif();
            }
            int orientation = 0;
            if (data != null) {
                orientation = data.findField(ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_ORIENTATION).getIntValue();
            } else {
                String[] projection = { Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION };
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)), projection, null, null, null);

                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    orientation = c.getInt(0);
                }
            }
            switch (orientation) {
                case 6:
                    return 90;
                case 8:
                    return 270;
                default:
                    return 0;

            }
            /*
             * } catch (JpegProcessingException e1) { e1.printStackTrace(); }
             * catch (MetadataException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
             */} catch (ImageReadException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

And this is the error log:

```
Description   Resource   Path   Location   Type
ImageReadException cannot be resolved to a type   Viewer.java   /Main/src/com/owleyes/moustache   line 687   Java Problem
ExifTagConstants cannot be resolved to a variable   Viewer.java   /Main/src/com/owleyes/moustache   line 666   Java Problem
TiffImageMetadata cannot be resolved to a type   Viewer.java   /Main/src/com/owleyes/moustache   line 660   Java Problem
Sanselan cannot be resolved   Viewer.java   /Main/src/com/owleyes/moustache   line 659   Java Problem
JpegImageMetadata cannot be resolved to a type   Viewer.java   /Main/src/com/owleyes/moustache   line 659   Java Problem
JpegImageMetadata cannot be resolved to a type   Viewer.java   /Main/src/com/owleyes/moustache   line 659   Java Problem
The import org.apache.sanselan cannot be resolved   Viewer.java   /Main/src/com/owleyes/moustache   line 11   Java Problem
The import org.apache.sanselan cannot be resolved   Viewer.java   /Main/src/com/owleyes/moustache   line 10   Java Problem
The import org.apache.sanselan cannot be resolved   Viewer.java   /Main/src/com/owleyes/moustache   line 9   Java Problem
The import org.apache.sanselan cannot be resolved   Viewer.java   /Main/src/com/owleyes/moustache   line 8   Java Problem
The import org.apache.sanselan cannot be resolved   Viewer.java   /Main/src/com/owleyes/moustache   line 7   Java Problem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly you don't have the needed library: [Apache Sanselan](http://commons.apache.org/imaging/).

Download the binaries here: http://commons.apache.org/imaging/download_sanselan.cgi, and extract the archive. Put the `sanselan-{version}.jar` in your project's `libs` directory. Recompile, and the errors should be gone.

Remember - Android doesn't have Sanselan library included out of the box.